# How to tune save operation with partitionBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, save, hdfs, shuffle

I need to partition dataset data by 6 columns: region/year/month/day/id/quadkey
Where on top level I have just binary region state, and at very bottom level is actually where it is get into many partitions.
So lets say we have 2 regions/usually 1 year/usually 1 month/3-4 days/100-150 ids/ 50-200 quadkeys
When I performing this I get really unbalanced shuffle operation and sometimes executors are failed due to exceeding memory limits.
Also I've noticed from History UI that some tasks at hat phase are very big (~15Gb) when others are much smaller (~1Gb).

I've tried to play with

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "3000")
```

Also I've tried to extend number of executors, but with same memory settings. That the errors that I get:

```
19/04/10 09:47:36 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
    ...
```

```
// stage: DataFrame
val partitionColumns = List("region", "year", "month", "day", "id", "quadkey")
stage.repartition(partitionColumns.map(new org.apache.spark.sql.Column(_)):_*)
      .write.partitionBy(partitionColumns:_*)
      .format("parquet")
      .option("compression", "gzip")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .save(destUrl)
```

I've expected to have balanced tasks at Save Stage, what shuffle settings I should set for this? Or I have to have executors with higher than 20-25 Gb memory ? What should be scaling approach in such case?

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to add more columns to `repartition`, & that column to have high cardinality (id of records or some random values)

if number of files become large then try setting `numPartitions` followed by partitioning columns.

`df.repartition(numPartitions, partition_cols_including_high_cardinality_column:_*).write........`

===========================================================================
Edit:

In scenarios where data is skewed with some partition combinations having more data than others, repartitioning them with same column might not be a good idea.
In repartition, all data matching partition key combination will first collected on same executor and one file will be produced if your partitionBy and repartition have same column arguments. So in this case, few partition combination will have files like ~15Gb and some like ~1Gb which is not ideal for datasources like HDFS

So what I'm suggesting here is to have repartition columns that distribute data evenly on executors. Consider this, we have repartitioned data on some column combination E, it produces lets say 400 rows for each executor to work on, then each executor will write its data based on partitionBy spec. And when you check your final output, each partition will have number of files equal to number of executors that received rows with same partitionBy spec. Number of executors are decided by repartition column spec.

What I suggested above is to have different set of columns for repartition which will help distribute data evenly on executors. And if for some reason its not possible on data, then add some random columns (technique called `salting`). Option of adding `numPartitions` fixes the upper bound of number of executors working on data thereby fixing number of files written to a partition directory. Setting numPartitions is extremely helpful when your repartition column has high cardinality as this can create many files in your output directories.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand

df.repartition(numPartitions, $"some_col_1", rand)
  .write.partitionBy("some_col")
  .parquet("partitioned_lake")
```

here by fixing numPartitions, we are sure that output for every partitionBy spec will have maximum of numPartitions files.

helpful link - http://tantusdata.com/spark-shuffle-case-2-repartitioning-skewed-data/
Hope this helps

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? So in addition to my columns you suggest add for example one more column that would shuffle data with good balance? To have kind of dame partitions? 
What I dont understand , let's say I would get minimal 10 000 partioned files. That would happen in case if all my partitions would be gathered per node in advance, right? So what you are suggesting is to repartition only by columns with high cardinality? In my case that would id and quadkeys I guess. 
Also I dont understand how numPartition works when your partition by columns

Comment: One thing that I don't understand is that numPartitions in that case decreases number of Tasks, so if I had 1500 partitions in my DF than I want to do partitionBy using some column with high cardinality in my case let's qk+rand, but then if I add option numPartition = 5, I see at Spark UI that I have exactly 5 tasks per that stage, which means that only 5 cores out of 80 would be loaded. And it takes forever. So I want to have both: small number of files and good performance, when I add small numPartiotions - balance is worse